# Quartz Scheduler sending email notification multiple time

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz for scheduling job. Job is to send reminder email every day at some particular time say 11:00AM. I am able to send reminder mail successfully, but the problem is that it sends more than 1 mails at same time. Sometime it sends 8 mails for 1 reminder request, sometime it sends 5. It seems same job is executed multiple time.

Following is my code,

```
JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(LmsJob.class)
                .withIdentity("lmsJob", org.quartz.Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP)
                .build();

        JobDataMap map = job.getJobDataMap();
        map.put("creditMonthlyLeaveBalance", creditMonthlyLeaveBalance);
        map.put("dailyUpdationTask", dailyUpdation);
        map.put("monthlyPayrollGenerationTask",
                monthlyPayrollGenerationTask);
        map.put("yearlyMaintenanceOfLeaveBalance",
                yearlyMaintenanceOfLeaveBalance);
        map.put("emailNotifier", emailNotifier);
        try {
            CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("lmsJob", "lmsJobGroup")
                    .forJob(job)
                    .startAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .withSchedule(
                            CronScheduleBuilder
                                    .cronSchedule("00 00 00 ? * *")).build();

            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
            scheduler.start();

            // scheduler.shutdown();

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please help me in this, let me know if anything else is needed from my side.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your entire code,which annotation you gave and stuff.So, I am guessing that you gave annotation like @QuartzEvery("3h"). As far I am guessing, your job is scheduled wrong.To make it run at a particular time of every day,try this...

```
QuartzManager implements Managed {
.
.
public void start() throws Exception {
.
.
QuartzDailyAt dailyAt = jobType.getAnnotation(QuartzDailyAt.class);
int hours[] = dailyAt.hours();
String hourString = 
Arrays.stream(hours).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(joining(","));
String cronExpression = String.format("0 0 %s * * ?", hourString);
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.
                    newTrigger().
                    startNow().
                    withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression).
                            inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"))).
                    build();
scheduler.scheduleJob(JobBuilder.newJob(jobType).build(), trigger);
scheduler.start();
.
. 
}
.
}
```

And interface as

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface QuartzDailyAt {
    int[] hours(); 
}
```

While running your job,add an annotation at the top of the class like

```
@QuartzDailyAt(hours = {7,8,9,15,16,17})
public class SomeJob extends QuartzJob {.....}
```

This gives you to run at every particular intervals of a particular time zone...(above it is IST)